# The method getX() is undefined for the type Point

Tags: android

I am getting  the method `getX()` is undefined for the type `Point`

my code is

```
public void addNewPoints(Point p)   {
    dataset.add(p.getX(), p.getY());
}
```

please help me how resolve this error

Comment: Post the **whole** stacktrace.

Comment: @m0skit0 his error message is from the compiler, not from runtime. There is no stack trace because there's no exception because the code can't build.

Comment: Then simply there's no `getX()` method, as the compiler states.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the class [`Point`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html) doesn't contain a public method named `getX()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing `java.awt.Point` with `android.graphics.Point`. The Android `Point`, documented at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html, has public `int x` and `int y` data members, while the AWT Point does have the `getX()` method.

Answer (score 0):

under source generate getters and setters but first you need something to get and set like this

```
class Point{
private int x;
private int y;

public void addNewPoints(Point p)   {
 dataset.add(p.getX(), p.getY());
}
}
```

Its a long story why private variables public methods to get and set variables, encapsulation, best practice.